# Silverlight Site Of Origin

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, web-services

If I have a silverlight application deployed to http://mydomain.com/MySilverlightApp I know that I can communicate with a web service using either:

- http://mydomain.com/Webservices/ or
- http://mydomain.com/MySilverlightApp/WebServices/.

If I use https://mydomain.com/Webservices I will get a security exception because the site of origin is inconsistent.

Likewise if I use http://mydomain2.com/Webservices I will again get a security exception because of site of origin issues.

I don't have the time to set this up or to test it at the moment but would I get a security exception if I used http://s1.mydomain.com/Webservices or http://s2.mydomain.com/Webservices?

I'm basically looking for a way to do load balancing but if my app is deployed to one location http://mydomain.com/MySilverlightApp/ what are the routes to overcome these security exceptions resulting from site of origin differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just allow cross domain access on your services?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get a security exception.

I see two ways to implement load balancing and avoiding cross domain exceptions:

1. [Make your Silverlight application a trusted application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#relaxed_crossdomain_access_restrictions)
2. [Setup a routing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx) ([WCF 4 version](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260996/Router-Service-in-WCF-4-0)) that publishes the client access policy file or is hosted at the site of origin.

Comment: I prefer not to force the user to accept the trusted application and wish to live in the sandbox per se.  As for the WCF routing service wouldn't all trafic eventually be sent and received over the main webserver.  For load balancing I'm talking more about tracfic and not CPU usage.

Comment: I understand but those are your options if you do not want to provide a client access policy file.